# Deserializer Class

Tags: c#, deserialization, memorystream

As per the requirement, created a customized deserializer class 'SafeSerializeDeserializeData', in which I have overridden BindToType method to return TypeToSerialize into, only if it is from the safeList or WhiteList created by us as per our application. But, in case of a memory stream BindToType is not being called, not sure why. But thinking, is it something to do with the 'buf' Array, can someone suggest how can I get this fixed that my overridden BindToType() gets called ?

Code Snippet :

```cs
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buf, 0, i))
{
    formatter.Binder = new SafeSerializeDeserializeData();

    object temp = formatter.Deserialize(ms);

    s = (string)temp;

}
```

Comment: what is the *data* here? looking at the last line, it looks like `string` - it wouldn't amaze me if some fundamental types (such as `int`, `object`, etc) have special handling and never need type resolution; but do you have a full example that shows *what you stored*? Also: I hate to say this, but the number of times most people should use `BinaryFormatter` is *very close to* zero. Not *quite* zero, but so close that ... well; let's just call it zero?

Comment: Make sure you set the memory stream to position zero before using.  The memory stream after filling it set to last position which usually fails when  you try to use.

Comment: Running some tests locally: indeed, some types skip `BindToType` - `string` being an example (but `int` *does* call `BindToType`). What is the actual data you're trying to bind here?

Comment: Yes, it is string, and as u say, that may be the case, but in our application it's used and have to find a way around it.

BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
   using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
   {
    formatter.Serialize(ms, Name); // Name is a String Type
    sock.Send(ms.GetBuffer());
   }

Comment: @jdweng did that.